# WSO2 Send alert/notification when API Definition is changed

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

we are struggling with this in our organization.
There are frequent changes in API Definition and the information that something was changed is not being communicated properly.

Is there any way to raise a notification every time the is an update to the API Definition? We are doing it with the integrated Swagger editor and Update content button.

Tried the Enable notifications which is only for new Version of an API.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to send a notification when changing the API definition. But you can [create a GitHub issue in WSO2 APIM repository](https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/new/choose), and product team will review the request and consider it for the next release.

Comment: to whoever flagged this, I think it's fine: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424111/11107541